# Append to dataframe with for loop. Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, for-loop, dataframe

I'm trying to loop through a list(y) and output by appending a row for each item to a dataframe.

```
y=[datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 29), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31)]
```

Desired Output:

```
Index                 Mean            Last
2017-03-29        1.5               .76
2017-03-30        2.3               .4
2017-03-31        1.2                1
```

Here is the first and last part of the code I currently have:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df5=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Mean','Last'],index=index)

for item0 in y:
.........
.........
    df=df.rename(columns = {0:'Mean'})
    df4=pd.concat([df, df3], axis=1)
    print (df4)
    df5.append(df4)
    print (df5)
```

My code only puts one row into the dataframe like as opposed to a row for each item in y:

```
Index                Mean             Last
2017-03-29         1.5                .76
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
y = [datetime(2017, 3, 29), datetime(2017, 3, 30),datetime(2017, 3, 31)]
m = [1.5,2.3,1.2]
l = [0.76, .4, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame([],columns=['time','mean','last'])
for y0, m0, l0 in zip(y,m,l):
    data = {'time':y0,'mean':m0,'last':l0}
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
```

and if you want `y` to be the `index`:

```
df.index = df.time
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to skin this, and it's hard to know which approach makes the most sense with the limited info given. But one way is to start with a dataframe that has only the index, iterate through the dataframe by row and populate the values from some other process. Here's an example of that approach:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y=[datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 29), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31)]
main_df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['Index']) 

#pop in the additional columns you want, but leave them blank
main_df['Mean'] = None
main_df['Last'] = None

#set the index
main_df.set_index(['Index'], inplace=True)
```

that gives us the following:

```
            Mean  Last
Index                 
2017-03-29  None  None
2017-03-30  None  None
2017-03-31  None  None
```

Now let's loop and plug in some made up random values:

```
## loop through main_df and add values
for (index, row) in main_df.iterrows():
    main_df.ix[index].Mean = np.random.rand()
    main_df.ix[index].Last = np.random.rand()
```

this results in the following dataframe which has the `None` values filled:

```
                Mean      Last
Index                         
2017-03-29  0.174714  0.718738
2017-03-30  0.983188  0.648549
2017-03-31   0.07809   0.47031
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that my for loop gets a particular Mean/Last Years Value for a single day.  So I need the for loop to output the Mean/Last value for _each_ day and put it into the main_df. I was able to use qbzenker's way by appending each column of my df4 to a list first. Your way would presuppose that I already have all outputs of y(i) in a df, which is what i'm trying to get. So is there any other simple way to do this?

Comment: you should give some example data of what you know and what structure it's in.